# use Java to run "tar" command, but it costs much time to generate the tar file

Tags: java, tar, runtime.exec

In my project, i need generate an agent for users, and the agent include some jars(about 22M),some source class(about 200k) and a XML. The server will generate different xml for defferent user,so I have to generate the agent dynamically. I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tar...")` to tar the files to generate agents. 
When I run the unit test , the generation costs a lot of time, about 2min for every agent. I cann't let the user wait a page for 2min...so do it exists any other way to make this program more efficiency, or there is another way to generate the agent fast and smoothly?? appreciate!

```
 /**
  * tar the agents
  * @param inputFiles agent files
  * @param outputFile agent tar
  * @param baseDir the directory path to run "tar" command
  */
 public static void tarFile(String[] inputFiles,String outputFile,String baseDir){
     String cmd="tar -zcf "+outputFile+" ";
     for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
        cmd+=inputFiles[i]+" ";
    }
     System.out.println(cmd);
     try {
        Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(baseDir));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        while ((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

this is my tar class, the param--basedir is to set the command's execution path

Comment: Are you compressing it?

Comment: have you tried threading in order to extract the files simultaneously?

Comment: 2 minutes for just over 22M is very slow. To make your software more efficient you must first find out why it is taking so long. You probably have a fault in your program somewhere, but without more information it is impossible to say more.

Comment: I just use the Java API -- Progress p=Runtime.getRuntime().exe("tar zcf folder"); and I don't need to extract files, what I have to do is to tar these files---some jars,my agent source class files,xml--into one file,that is my agent. my agent uses a lot of jars, about 22M, and I have to publish my source class file with these jars.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) to create the `tar` archive directly in Java.
See [TarArchiveOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveOutputStream.html).

Here a complete servlet that creates that `tar` output on the fly:

```
import java.io.*;   
import javax.servlet.http.*;    
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.*;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

public class Web extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String[] files = { 
                "/path/to/file1",
                "/path/to/file2",
        };

        resp.setContentType("application/x-tar");
        try (TarArchiveOutputStream out = new TarArchiveOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream())) {
            for (String name: files) {
                File file = new File(name);
                TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry(file);
                out.putArchiveEntry(entry);
                try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                }
                out.closeArchiveEntry();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The client will start receiving the archive instantly, without having to wait for the `tar` file to be created in advance. Also this does not require writing the archive to disc.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the actual tar command which you pass to Runtime.getRuntime().exec.

There are 4 factors which really influence the speed of zipping up files into a tarball:

1. CPU speed on the box
2. I/O speed on the box
3. Amount of source data to archive
4. Compression

rzymek pointed out that you can use Apache Commons Compress to generate the file natively.  However, I am not sure that would be any faster unless we understand what the constraint from the command-line approach is.

If you just tar it yourself using a shell, is the speed comparable?  If so, try reducing the compression ratio or even turning it off entirely (removing the "z" option in `tar czf`).

If you are compressing the tar file and it needs to be compressed, then if the XML is small, you could pre-compress the JAR files (I think they already are compressed if I recall, but you may need to check the compression ratio) and then make the tarball uncompressed since compressing a compressed file accomplishes nothing (and sometimes is slower!)

Comment: I have paste my code above, please give me any advice you know, thanks! you  mention that removing "z" option, I test the new command, it didn't work fast, also cost about 2 min

Comment: This suggests that compression is not the source of the slow response.  How big is the resulting file after removing the z option?

Comment: about 24.5M. if add  z option, about 22M

Comment: Is this repeatable on different computers with different hardware specs?